# Rails, React, Browserify , react-rails gem - Cannot find module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, browserify, react-rails, browserify-rails

I am following this great tutorial: [setting-up-react-in-ruby-on-rails-part-1](http://bit.ly/1Mttwsa)

I am getting this error: Error: Cannot find module xxx from xxx

**test-component.es6.js**

```
React   = require('react/addons');

let  TestTwo = require('./components/test-two.es6.js');

let TestComponent = React.createClass({
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
    <TestTwo />
  </div>

);
}
});
module.exports = TestComponent;
```

**component.js**

```
//= require_tree ./components

// You'll probably want this if your using babel
require("babelify/polyfill");
var app = window.app = global.app = {};
//React bootstrap modules

var TestComponent = require('./components/test-component.es6.js');
app.TestComponent = TestComponent;
```

*When I setup it this way it works but TestTwo component is no prerendered (I use prerender:true)*

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

> After server edit in this setup content get prerendered but I need to restart server every time Data is changed in browser but when I open Source View old data is there not new !?.

**test-component.es6.js**

```
React   = require('react/addons');

let TestComponent = React.createClass({
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
    <app.TestTwo />
  </div>

);
}
});
module.exports = TestComponent;
```

**component.js**

```
//= require_tree ./components

// You'll probably want this if your using babel
require("babelify/polyfill");
var app = window.app = global.app = {};
//React bootstrap modules

var TestTwo = require('./components/test-two.es6.js');
app.TestTwo = TestTwo;

var TestComponent = require('./components/test-component.es6.js');
app.TestComponent = TestComponent;
```

TestTwo component is simply returning some text.

**text.html.erb** is same for both setups

```
<%= react_component 'app.TestComponent', {title:"Hello, Back"}, {prerender:true} %>
```

**Win7 64-bit OS**

Comment: did you found any solution for this? i have the same problem..

Comment: But i found a running configuration.. Maybe it helps you: http://www.lampesberger.net/blog/2016/03/16/react-slash-redux-with-rails-3-dot-2-and-sprockets/

Comment: Thanks, this is even with Redux, that is nice :)